# How to download automatically multiple files from the same library of sharepoint using powershell

Tags: powershell

I am new on Powershell and I am trying to loop the content of a remote library in order to download all the zip files present inside the sharepoint library. The following working function is involved in the download of one single file. Could you please help

```
#Load SharePoint CSOM Assemblies
Add-Type -Path "C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\16\ISAPI\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.dll"
Add-Type -Path "C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\16\ISAPI\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Runtime.dll"


Function Download-FileFromLibrary()
{
    param
    (
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)] [string] $SiteURL,
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)] [string] $SourceFile,
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)] [string] $TargetFile
    )

    Try {
        #Setup Credentials to connect
        $Cred= Get-Credential
        $Credentials = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.SharePointOnlineCredentials($Cred.Username, $Cred.Password)

        #Setup the context
        $Ctx = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext($SiteURL)
        $Ctx.Credentials = $Credentials

        #sharepoint online powershell download file from library
        $FileInfo = [Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.File]::OpenBinaryDirect($Ctx,$SourceFile)
        $WriteStream = [System.IO.File]::Open($TargetFile,[System.IO.FileMode]::Create)
        $FileInfo.Stream.CopyTo($WriteStream)
        $WriteStream.Close()

        Write-host -f Green "File '$SourceFile' Downloaded to '$TargetFile' Successfully!" $_.Exception.Message
  }
    Catch {
        write-host -f Red "Error Downloading File!" $_.Exception.Message
    }
}

#Set parameter values
$SiteURL="xxx"
$SourceFile="xxx" 
$TargetFile="xxx"

#Call the function to download file
#Download-FileFromLibrary -SiteURL $SiteURL -SourceFile $SourceFile -TargetFile $TargetFile


Download-FileFromLibrary -SiteURL $SiteURL -SourceFile $SourceFile -TargetFile $TargetFile
```

Answer (score 1):

Hi here is my complete working code, I have tested this which is working fine.

```
    #Load SharePoint CSOM Assemblies
    #Add-Type -Path "C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\16\ISAPI\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.dll"
    #Add-Type -Path "C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\16\ISAPI\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Runtime.dll"
    cls
    $fileName = "File_Downloading_Report" #'yyyyMMddhhmm   yyyyMMdd
    $enddate = (Get-Date).tostring("yyyyMMddhhmmss")
    #$filename =  $enddate + '_VMReport.doc'  
    $logFileName = $fileName +"_"+ $enddate+"_Log.txt"   
    $invocation = (Get-Variable MyInvocation).Value  
    $directoryPath = Split-Path $invocation.MyCommand.Path

     $directoryPathForLog=$directoryPath+"\"+"LogFiles"
     if(!(Test-Path -path $directoryPathForLog))  
        {  
            New-Item -ItemType directory -Path $directoryPathForLog
            #Write-Host "Please Provide Proper Log Path" -ForegroundColor Red   
        }   


#$logPath = $directoryPath + "\" + $logFileName 
$logPath = $directoryPathForLog + "\" + $logFileName   
$isLogFileCreated = $False 



#DLL location

$directoryPathForDLL=$directoryPath+"\"+"Dependency Files"
if(!(Test-Path -path $directoryPathForDLL))  
        {  
            New-Item -ItemType directory -Path $directoryPathForDLL
            #Write-Host "Please Provide Proper Log Path" -ForegroundColor Red   
        } 

#DLL location

$clientDLL=$directoryPathForDLL+"\"+"Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.dll"
$clientDLLRuntime=$directoryPathForDLL+"\"+"Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.dll"

Add-Type -Path $clientDLL
Add-Type -Path $clientDLLRuntime


#File Download location

$directoryPathForFileDownloadLocation=$directoryPath+"\"+"Downloaded Files"
if(!(Test-Path -path $directoryPathForFileDownloadLocation))  
        {  
            New-Item -ItemType directory -Path $directoryPathForFileDownloadLocation
            #Write-Host "Please Provide Proper Log Path" -ForegroundColor Red   
        } 

#File Download location



function Write-Log([string]$logMsg)  
{   
    if(!$isLogFileCreated){   
        Write-Host "Creating Log File..."   
        if(!(Test-Path -path $directoryPath))  
        {  
            Write-Host "Please Provide Proper Log Path" -ForegroundColor Red   
        }   
        else   
        {   
            $script:isLogFileCreated = $True   
            Write-Host "Log File ($logFileName) Created..."   
            [string]$logMessage = [System.String]::Format("[$(Get-Date)] - {0}", $logMsg)   
            Add-Content -Path $logPath -Value $logMessage   
        }   
    }   
    else   
    {   
        [string]$logMessage = [System.String]::Format("[$(Get-Date)] - {0}", $logMsg)   
        Add-Content -Path $logPath -Value $logMessage   
    }   
} 



#The below function will download the file from SharePoint Online library.

Function FileDownLoadFromSPOnlineLibrary()
{
    param
    (
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)] [string] $SPOSiteURL,
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)] [string] $SourceFilePath,
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)] [string] $TargetFilePath,
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)] [string] $UserName,
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)] [string] $Password
    )

    Try 
    {



        $securePassword= $Password | ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText -Force  
        #Setup the Context
        $ctx = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext($SPOSiteURL)
        $ctx.Credentials = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.SharePointOnlineCredentials($UserName, $securePassword)


        #sharepoint online powershell download file from library
        $fileInfo = [Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.File]::OpenBinaryDirect($ctx,$SourceFilePath)
        $writeStream = [System.IO.File]::Open($TargetFilePath,[System.IO.FileMode]::Create)
        $fileInfo.Stream.CopyTo($writeStream)
        $writeStream.Close()

        Write-host -f Green "File '$SourceFilePath' has been downloaded to '$TargetFilePath' successfully!"
    }
    Catch 
    {

            $ErrorMessage = $_.Exception.Message +"in Downloading File!: " +$SourceFilePath
            Write-Host $ErrorMessage -BackgroundColor Red
            Write-Log $ErrorMessage 


    }
}


#Parameters
$siteURL="https://globalsharepoint.sharepoint.com/sites/TestSite/"
$listName="Documents"
$fromDate="2019-10-28"
$toDate="2019-11-10"
$downloadLocation=$directoryPathForFileDownloadLocation;
$userName = "YourSPOAccount@YourTenantDomain.com"
$password = "YourPassWord"
$securePassword= $password | ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText -Force
#$batchSize =1000

#Parameters ends here.


#Setup the Context
$ctx = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext($siteURL)
$ctx.Credentials = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.SharePointOnlineCredentials($userName, $securePassword)

#Get the List
$list = $ctx.Web.Lists.GetByTitle($listName)
$ctx.Load($list)
$ctx.ExecuteQuery()
$emptyString = ""
$BatchSize="1000"
#Define CAML Query to get Files from the list in batches
$Query = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.CamlQuery


#Here in the below two line "T13:35:58Z" and "T13:36:34Z" are hard coded static value - because while we construct this camel query thru the camel query builder these values gets appended to the date value, so we need this.
$startDateVar=$fromDate+"T13:35:58Z"  
$endDateVar=$toDate+"T13:36:34Z"
#Here in the below two line "T13:35:58Z" and "T13:36:34Z" are hard coded static value - ends here.


$Query.ViewXml = "@
    <View Scope='Recursive'>
        <Query>
             <OrderBy><FieldRef Name='ID' Ascending='True'/></OrderBy>

        </Query>
        <RowLimit>$BatchSize</RowLimit>
    </View>"



$count =0

#Get List Items in Batches
Do
{


    $ListItems = $List.GetItems($Query)
    $Ctx.Load($ListItems)
    $Ctx.ExecuteQuery()
    $ListItems.Count

    #Update Postion of the ListItemCollectionPosition
    $Query.ListItemCollectionPosition = $ListItems.ListItemCollectionPosition
    $Query.ListItemCollectionPosition

    If ($ListItems.Count -eq 0) 
    { 
    Break
    }

    $downloadItemCount=1;

    #Extract the each list item from the List Items collection.
    ForEach($Item in $ListItems)
    {                  
          #Example to Item metadata - this can be used if we want to download based on some item metadata condition.
          #$documentStatus=$Item["documentStatusColumnName"]         
            try
            {

                $Ctx.Load($Item.File)
                $Ctx.ExecuteQuery()
                #$eTagVal=$Item.File.ETag



                #$SiteURL=$SiteURL

                #https://globalsharepoint.sharepoint.com/sites/TestSite/Shared%20Documents/LegalDoc.docx        
                $SourceFile=$Item.File.ServerRelativeUrl;
                #$TargetFile="C:\PowerShell\DownLoadFilesFromSPOnline\Downloaded Files\LegalDoc.docx" 
                $TargetFile=$downloadLocation+"\"+$Item.File.Name; 


                if($SourceFile.Contains(".zip")) **#Checking file type .zip**
                {
                $count++;            

                #Call the function to download file
                FileDownLoadFromSPOnlineLibrary -SPOSiteURL $SiteURL -SourceFilePath $SourceFile -TargetFilePath $TargetFile -UserName $UserName -Password $Password

                }

                $fileDownloadingMessage=$downloadItemCount.ToString()+": "+$Item.File.Name; 
                Write-Host $fileDownloadingMessage -BackgroundColor DarkGreen
                Write-Log $fileDownloadingMessage

        $downloadItemCount++

        }
        catch
        { 
            $ErrorMessage = $_.Exception.Message +"in: " +$Item.File.Name
            Write-Host $ErrorMessage -BackgroundColor Red
            Write-Log $ErrorMessage 

        }


    }
    Write-Host "============================================================="
    Write-Host $count
    Write-Host "============================================================="

}While ($Query.ListItemCollectionPosition -ne $null)
```

**File Input:**
[image: This is my list of documents in SPO online library]

**Execute the above code:**

https://i0.wp.com/global-sharepoint.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/11/FileDownalod1.png?w=428&h=224&ssl=1

**Output: all zip files are downloaded to the given location**

https://i0.wp.com/global-sharepoint.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/11/FileDownalod2.png?w=648&h=224&ssl=1

Note:

Could not upload the image screenshots here, so added the image reference URL.

**Reference URL :**

https://global-sharepoint.com/2019/11/09/how-to-download-file-from-sharepoint-online-document-library-using-powershell-csom-from-the-given-date/

**The below dll should be kept as below:**
[image]

**The below code is to handle the getting files from folders, sub folders:**

```
$Query2 = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.CamlQuery
$Query2.ViewXml = '<View Scope="RecursiveAll"><Query><Where><Eq><FieldRef Name="FSObjType" /><Value Type="Integer">0</Value></Eq></Where><OrderBy><FieldRef Name="ID" /></OrderBy></Query></View>'
$ListItems2 = $list.GetItems($Query2)
$Ctx.Load($ListItems2)
$Ctx.ExecuteQuery()
foreach($Item in $ListItems2)
{

     $Ctx.Load($Item.File)
     $Ctx.ExecuteQuery()
     $SourceFile=$Item.File.ServerRelativeUrl;
     $TargetFile=$downloadLocation+"\"+$Item.File.Name;

      if($SourceFile.Contains(".zip"))
        {
        FileDownLoadFromSPOnlineLibrary -SPOSiteURL $SiteURL -SourceFilePath $SourceFile -TargetFilePath $TargetFile -UserName $UserName -Password $Password
        }

}
```

Comment: Hi! Thank you for your answer!! After having tried with your code I faced an error message telling me that $ctx.ExecuteQuery has no arguments, what can I do? Many thanks

Comment: @LeonardoReffosco : I just executed now again its working fine without any error. I think you are missing the reference dll. The location where creating this .ps1 file , in the same location you need to create a folder named as "Dependency Files" and inside that place two SP dlls - for more information please refer the reference link mentioned in the answer. Still if you face any issue please mention the line number with that line code....Added the dll reference screenshot in the answer section.

Comment: It seems that the context is not initialised line 147

Comment: Context is initialized, with the same code I just executed again without error:$ctx = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext($siteURL)
$ctx.Credentials = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.SharePointOnlineCredentials($userName, $securePassword)
#Get the List
$list = $ctx.Web.Lists.GetByTitle($listName)
$ctx.Load($list)
$ctx.ExecuteQuery()

Comment: Exception calling "ExecuteQuery" with 0 arguments: "Cannot contact site at the specified URL" I am sure about the website

Comment: Ohh...ok - something wrong with your site url and authentication - please check you have access to that site and you can access it. What I can say it from the coding perspective this is 100 percent working :-)

Comment: sorry for the question, but also powershell requires an access to sharepoint even if i have already a working account?

Comment: Its ok Leonardo, I am pleased to answer. Having permission in site is enough we don't need separate permission for PowerShell, the only thing is while you are opening the PowerShell ISE or PowerShell command prompt, need to open as an administrator by right click on it.

Comment: Thank you Habibur Rahaman for your efforts. I am with VPN of the compnay and I tried with your suggestion. The error occurs anyway. Maybe could be VPN or the url. I will ask to collegue tomorrow

Comment: Even if I should add that my code is working for one file. So I have to exclude that this is a problem of VPN. Do you think that the issue could be that I am trying to access a sublibrary of a sublibrary of Documents?

Comment: Yes the problem was this one: how can i set the sublibrary?

Comment: Your code is working for Documents but if i set the sublibrary of the sublibrary, where the zip files are located is not working

Comment: I think you meant sublibrary as folders inside the document library.... if yes it should work as I have used the recursive query in the camel query.... anyway I will check this part one more time....

Comment: Could you please advise me where i should modify the script to go through subfolders? Many thanks

Comment: @LeonardoReffosco: Updated the answer - to handle the folders and sub folders etc.

Comment: Thank you, I tried with your code anyhow it seems that the CAML Query is retrieving more than 5000 rows so it is exceeding the limit of sharepoint online. How can I point to a specific subfolder called ZIP present inside a folder within Documents library?

Comment: Hi - to restrict the number below 5000 in camel query, need to pass the row limit inside the camel query... to be more handy with camel query, I recommend you to install the camel query builder tool :-) to get the folder we need to use GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl property like below :
$SourceFolder = $Web.GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl($Web.ServerRelativeUrl+$FolderRelativeUrl)
$Ctx.Load($SourceFolder)
$Ctx.ExecuteQuery()

Comment: @Leonardo Reffosco : Please mark the reply as answer if you find it helpful. It will help other community members with similar issues. Thanks for understanding this.